# Prove function $g$ has a continuous expansion $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, continuity

I'm trying to expand the function $$g(x,y) = \arctan \left(\frac{1-xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$ to some function $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

We know already it's continuous on $\mathbb R^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\}$, so to find a proper candidate for the value $f(0,0)$, we can check any approaching limit.

For example $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x, 0)= \lim_{x\to 0} \arctan \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ So if $f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$, the value has to be equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

The problem I'm having is how to now prove if $f$ actually is continuous.

So for $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there has to $\exists \delta > 0$, so that $|(x,y) - (0,0)| < \delta \implies |f(x,y) - f(0,0)| < \epsilon$.
When I try to look at $$\left| \arctan \frac{1-xy}{x^2+y^2} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right|$$ I then kind of become stuck, trying to see what the value is less as.

I hope my question is somewhat clear. I'm just searching for the next step in proving continuity if anybody can offer some help. Thank you all in advance. :)

Comment: Regarding language: better is "extension to", not "expansion"...

Comment: @paulgarrett I think that the user is a Italian citizen like me :-). I use $\operatorname{arctg}$ to my school.

Comment: @paulgarret Thank you, noted! English is indeed not my first language and my sleepy self thought I did't need to google the correct translation (now I know I probably should next time...). :)

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint}$:

$$\left|\arctan\left(\frac{1-xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right| = \left|\arctan\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{1-xy}\right)\right| \leq \left|\frac{x^2+y^2}{1-xy}\right|$$

in a neighborhood of $0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! Helps a lot. :)